# digne jusqu’à la dureté, pur jusqu’à la sauvagerie

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Ça veut dire quoi, être

> digne jusqu’à la dureté, pur jusqu’à la sauvagerie.

Source: [Les misérables Tome III](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Answer (score 1):

Ça veut dire avoir une attitude extrême, fanatique, intolérante, ne pas faire preuve de souplesse et de retenue dans l'expression de sa dignité et de sa pureté.

Answer (score 1):

« Digne jusqu'à la dureté » vise à caractériser une dignité qui est fondée sur des principes qui vont jusqu'à l'extrême et qui sont respectés avec intransigeance; cette intransigeance peut être manifestée non seulement à l'égard de l'être dont cette sorte de  dignité est un attribut mais aussi à l'égard de son entourage, lequel doit se plier à ces principes extrêmes. « Pur jusqu'à la sauvagerie » est encore une caractérisation sur le plan de l'aspect extrême et intransigeant avec lequel une qualité peut être trouvée dans un être humain ou une organisation humaine. Cela signifie que l'être dont l'âme a embrassé de tels principes de pureté peut porter l'individu qu'elle habite à des actes de sauvagerie sur lui même mais aussi sur son prochain ; on trouve à profusion des exemples de cette pureté jusqu'à la sauvagerie perpétrée sur la personne même dont cette pureté est un attribut, dans les vie des saints de la religion chrétienne : la pureté dans ce cas peut inclure des modes de vie que beaucoup de monde considère  comme cruels, inhumains; elle peut aller jusqu'à des actes comme la flagellation, où le parcours à genou de longues distances en dépit de genoux ensanglantés ; évidemment cela fait partie des exemples  extrêmes de pureté jusqu'à la sauvagerie ; il est déjà légitime de référer à un excès de pureté dans ce sens, si l'on peut vraiment parler de pureté, pour des actes dont la sauvagerie est loin d'être aussi flagrante.